# Is there any way to look for and extract a string consisting of 2 characters followed by any 8 digit number in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a query to extract a 10 digit string from a larger string. This string would consist of two characters followed by 8 digits e.g.'EL12345678'

I was previously using the below query, where the variable @prefix can consist of any two characters. However i have come across some cases where these characters are used elsewhere within the string causing it to extract the wrong code.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(message_key, (SELECT CHARINDEX(@prefix, message_key)), 10) AS pcn,
       Message_ID
FROM MQ
WHERE Message_Status != 'processed'
  AND Message_Status != 'bad'
  AND message_status != 'new'
  AND Message_Time > DATEADD(DAY, -@days, dbo.dateonlyVB())
  AND Message_MethodName = CASE WHEN @prefix = 'DN' THEN 'SaveJob' ELSE 'savedetails' END;
```

I tried to use patindex and some wildcards to see if i could specify that it was a number that followed the variable, however this didn't seem to work when i tried it.

I am expecting it to be able to extract a string something like 'EL12345678' from a larger string which can be anywhere in the region of 300+ characters long. However my query is currently occasionally extracting strings like 'elValvef":' instead.

Any help with this at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not abbreviate the first 3 clauses to `Message_Status NOT IN ('processed','bad','new')` Also, that Sclar Function is probably going to be a performance killer is it's Multiline; unless you're using 2019's inlining scalar functionality? I'd also suggest moving the last clause to be boolean logic.

Comment: That scalar function is going to be a performance killer no matter how it is coded. Scalar functions in general are bad. In the where clause they are horrific.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions all, performance isn't too much of an issue in this case as this is a query i'm manually running when needed and only takes a second or so to run at the minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use `patindex()`:

```
select substring(largerstring,
                 patindex('%__[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', largerstring
                         ), 10
                )
```

Comment: Thanks, this is along the lines of what i'm going for. This doesn't seem to work when i try it though. When i used your exact code it simply gave me the prefix 'EL' i believe this is because it's only searching through the prefix rather than the message_key field. I tried modifying it by replacing the prefix's with the message_key and adding the @prefix instead of the two __ but it didnt work. Strangely it works when i place the actual string 'EL', but when i use patindex('%'+prefix+'%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', Message_Key) it doesn't.

Comment: Hold on figured out my issue and this is now working perfectly. Cheers for the advice on this! For any interested i used: select substring(Message_Key, patindex('%'+@prefix+'[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', Message_Key), 10)

Comment: @jamesmcrow If this suggestion resolves your problem, then please do your part as a member of the SO community and mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED BASED ON OP COMMENTS**

As Gordon showed, you can do this:

```
SELECT item = SUBSTRING(@string,PATINDEX('%'+@prefix+'[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', @string),8)
```

You can also use [NGrams8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams) for this kind of thing:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000) = 'ABCXXXAB12345678 blah blah', @prefix VARCHAR(2) = 'AB';

SELECT item = ng.token
FROM   dbo.NGrams8k(@string,10) AS ng
WHERE  PATINDEX('%'+@prefix+'[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',ng.token) = 1;
```

**OLD:**

```
This string would consist of two characters followed by 8 digits
e.g.'EL12345678'
```

If it's that simple you can just do this:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(1000) = 'EL12345678';

SELECT SUBSTRING(@string,3,8)

--Returns: 12345678
```

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear enough, that was an example of what i wanted as an output. The actual strings can be extremely long. I said 300 characters but can actually be in the thousands.